# Dismiss messages on lock screen on cyanogen

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens

When your phone is locked and you receive an update which you don't want to unlock your phone for. Is there a setting to make it possible to dismiss it without unlocking the screen? Would even be better to only make certain apps dismissable without unlocking.

using android 6.0.1 cyanogenmod 13.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You can slide down when you get a type of message, press it for 2 seconds and press the info icon, and than you can disable persistent notification on lock screen. 
When looking at this question([Why are some lollipop notifications able to be swiped away on lockscreen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120671/why-are-some-lollipop-notifications-able-to-be-swiped-away-on-lockscreen)) Doesn't seem like you can change the type of notification.

Comment: The way I see it, it doesn't exactly answer your question ("dismiss without unlocking"), rather it's a workaround that simply disables _all_ notifications for what you don't want. Still, as long as it works fine for you...

Comment: Indeed it doesn't actually does what I want but I don't think 'make persistent notification swipeable' is a feature. Too bad though. It should be up to the user and not the app whether or not you can swipe away a notification on the lock screen